# Export plotly to powerpoint in R

Tags: r, plot, powerpoint, plotly, ggplotly

Is it possible to export plotly/ggplotly plot to Powerpoint and keep its interactivity? I mean by that for example to allow user to change colors of plot lines, thickness, etc.

Example code:

```
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_point(aes(text = paste("Clarity:", clarity))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = cut, fill = cut)) + facet_wrap(~ cut)
gg <- ggplotly(p)
```

Btw, using `webshot` package to export plot as `.png` file is not a solution. And I should be able to code this solution and automate from R or any other programming language - online tools or any other applications where it should be clicked by user to get result do not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried any of these https://www.google.com/search?q=insert+plotly+into+powerpoint ?

Comment: None of those solution can be used directly from R.

Comment: maybe using powerpoint online: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668a1d-2299-4af3-91e1-ae57af723a60

Comment: You could just use the presentation software built into R. Go to File and New File and select R Presentation, easier way to present your data and keep interactivity if that's what your looking for.

Comment: check `officer` package at : `https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/` AND `https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html`